# How to compare two datetime values in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for comparing two datetime columns in SQL Server, for example, I have data like

**TableA**:

```
Start Date    "2016-11-04 06:00:00.000"
End Date      "2016-11-04 08:15:00.000"
```

And I need to compare value of Table A with Table B which is as follows

**TableB**:

```
Start Date    "2016-11-01 02:30:00.000"
End Date      "2016-11-30 08:00:00.000"
```

Expecting that it should not match, because the End Date in TableB is greater than End Date of TableA.

So far I have tried is, but its not returning me desired result.

```
(TableA.StartDate BETWEEN TableB.startdatetime AND TableB.enddatetime) 
OR (TableA.EndDate BETWEEN TableB.startdatetime AND TableB.enddatetime) 
OR (TableB.startdatetime BETWEEN TableA.StartDate AND TableB.enddatetime) 
OR (TableB.enddatetime BETWEEN TableA.StartDate AND TableB.enddatetime)
```

Any idea, what I am missing here..

Regards,

Comment: Can you give an example of two sets of datetime fields which _would_ meet your definition of a "match?"

Comment: (TableA.StartDate = TableB.startdatetime 
AND TableA.EndDate = TableB.EndDate) will be true if corresponding start and enddates are equal. Putting NOT in front will return true if they are not.

Comment: You have two date boundaries which means there are six different ways they can be associated: 1. One period is completely before the other one; 2. one period overlaps a start time; 3 One period overlaps an end time; 4. One period is completely within the other period; 5. The periods match perfectly; 6. One period is completely after the second period. Your example is number 4. What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: The matching record in TableA will be : - Start Date:- "2016-11-04 06:00:00.000"
End Date: - "2016-11-04 08:00:00.000" OR Start Date:- "2016-11-04 06:00:00.000"
End Date: - "2016-11-04 07:30:00.000". The Unmatch record in TableA will Be :- Start Date:- "2016-11-04 01:30:00.000"
End Date: - "2016-11-04 08:00:00.000" (because start date time is higher than in TableB)

Comment: @Nick, I am with Number 4. One period is to be completely within the other period.

Comment: Are you saying that you want some logic that will allow you to identify pairs when a period is wholly within another period? (You've still not really explained what you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue using below condition. I think SQL Server considers only Date part if we try to compare along with Time. Hence I had to separate the time part to compare the same.

```
TableA.StartDate >= TableB.startdatetime AND TableA.StartDate <= TableB.enddatetime  
  AND TableA.EndDate >= TableB.startdatetime AND TableA.EndDate <= TableB.enddatetime  
  AND (CAST(TableA.StartDate AS time) BETWEEN CAST(TableB.startdatetime AS time) 
  AND CAST(TableB.enddatetime AS time) )
  AND (CAST(TableA.EndDate AS time) BETWEEN CAST(TableB.startdatetime AS time) 
  AND CAST(TableB.enddatetime AS time) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to find 2 values in TABLEA which exist together in TABLEB (both ST, and ED in the same record.)
I'm guessing the two tables have no other matching value other than these two exact date matches, for example a unique ID.

After a little testing:

```
 select st, ed 
 from tableA
 where exists (select st, ed from tableB)
```

Returns every single value. Useless.

```
select * from 
tableA  a join
tableB b on a.st = b.st 
and a.ed = b.ed
```

Returns millions of matches, useless. The table only has 1000 records.

```
select * from 
tableA  a join
tableB b on a.st = b.st 
and a.ed = b.ed
and a.id = b.id
```

returns 27 matches. The correct answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not matching, it should be date and time comparison between two value set.